# Having the maven parent project in Eclipse for a flat project layout

Tags: eclipse, maven, parent, multi-module

I'm trying to "mavenize" an existing EAR application.

I've read the [guidelines to create a multi-module project with WTP](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/examples/multi-module-projects.html) and created a "flat project layout".

My problem is that when typing the command `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, I've got the .projects, .classpath and .settings created for the ear, ejb and war projects, but not for parent project, which is a `<packaging>pom</packaging>`.

Do you know how to do this ?

Actually, the goal is to commit to the SCM (SVN) all the changes directly from Eclipse, that's why I must have the parent-project in the handled projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally did is to create a simple .project in my `project-parent` dir :

```
<projectDescription>
  <name>project-parent</name>
</projectDescription>
```

Eclipse recognizes it and it is not system dependent, what I finally wanted.